# Ansible: parsing command output

Tags: parsing, ansible

New to Ansible. There has to be a simpler way to do this:  I need to issue a command (e.g. ps), and go through the return elements one by one, skipping the first element which has the column headings (e.g. PID, etc. in this case). I am only interested in the process names, not the other column values.

What's the easiest way of doing this? Below is my approach (which may not be the best way). I *finally* whittled down the list to omit the first element. Do I read into a separate array, loop through each item, and use awk or sed to filter on the process name?

```yaml
  name: Get process
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Get process
      command: "ps"
      register: ps_output

    - name: Set list length
      set_fact:
        array_end_index: "{{ ps_output.stdout_lines | length - 1 }}"
      
    - name: List all but last item
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ ps_output.stdout_lines[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(1, (array_end_index | int)) | list }}"
```

Comment: I'd bet the [`ps_output.stdout_lines | reject("match", ...)` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#reject) (with that ["match"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) bit being the test having that name) will get you pretty close

Answer (score 0):

Your text says to skip the "first element which has the column headings", but when I run your example it skips the first AND last lines.  Not sure which you want, but since you already have a list in the `ps_output.stdout_lines` variable, so use the Python slice notation to return entries to easily remove from either or both ends of the list.  (Note that the list is a zero-indexed list.)

To drop both the first and last list entries:

```
- name: Get process
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Get process
      command: "ps"
      register: ps_output

    - name: List all but last item
      debug: 
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ ps_output.stdout_lines[1:-1] }}"
```

If you just want to drop the first line, change the `loop:` slice to `[1:]`.  If you want to drop just the last line, use `[:-1]`.

See [Understanding Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) for more information.

Comment: That worked. Thanks Dan! And thanks for pointing me in the right direction.